# reflection in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reflection

I have a json object;

```
a.Name = "John";
a.Nick = "Smith";
a.Info = "hi there";
```

and some html like this:

```
<input id="Name" />
<input id="Nick" />
<input id="Info" />
```

is it possible to automatically set the values of these inputs according the object's property names ?

What I'd like to do is to loop through the object's properties and look for an input with same id and set it's value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since IDs should be unique anyway, here’s a more efficient solution:

```
$.each(a, function(k, v) {
  $('#' + k).val(v);
});
```

Of course, this is even faster:

```
$.each(a, function(k, v) {
  (document.getElementById(k) || {}).value = v;
});
```

If you prefer not to use jQuery at all, you could do it like this:

```
for (var i in a) {
  (document.getElementById(i) || {}).value = a[i];
});
```

**Edit:** Updated the last two answers, since OP mentioned that some inputs might not exist.

Comment: getElementById() is internally used by jQuery when using a # selector so it won't be much faster ;-)

Comment: Btw, +1 for the # selector, IDs "should" (depends of the developer ;-)) be unique. I just didn't want to apply some val() to anything else than an input, in case you have a duplicated ID with the same key.

Answer (score 7):

You want to do this?

```
$.each(a, function(k,v) {
    $('input[id='+k+']').val(v);
})
```

Comment: some inputs might not exist, is this ok?

Comment: Yes, the val() method will be applied on a empty jQuery object, which is OK, it won't throw any error.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for (var prop in a) { 
  alert(propertyName + ' => ' + a[propertyName]); 
}
```

this version don't need jQuery ;)